# Define what class contains

Tags: python

Ok, this might be a very stupid question and it might not be possible, or I am thinking in a twisted way. So, consider this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = self.x ** 2


class MyList:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list)

foo = [MyClass(x=1), MyClass(x=2)]
bar = MyList(list=foo)

for i in bar:
    print(i.x, i.y)
```

Ok, here we have two classes: `MyClass` is just something very ordinary and nothing special. It has two instance attributes: `x` and `y`.
`MyList`, on the other hand, should be a class which defines an iterator which should only contain elements from the first class `MyClass`!

Then I create two instances of `MyClass`, put them in a list `foo`, and use this list to create an instance of `MyList` (`bar`).

Now, again, the list passed to `MyList` should only contain `MyClass` elements! What I want is Python to be aware of this fact! When I write a loop where I iterate over the contents of `bar`, I would like that Python knows that the elements in `bar` are `MyClass` objects.

A major inconvenience in my program for now is that Python is not aware of this and the autocompletion does not work. In other words: In the loop, when I write `i.`, I would like all the possible arguments to pop up (in this case `x` and `y`). Can I define some magic method in Python for `MyList` which makes Python aware of the contents of this list?

Comment: I think there are two separate questions: how to enforce MyList to contain only instances of MyClass (note: I'd make MyList a subclass of `list` and overwrite append, init, etc.) and how to make the autocompletion work (note: `__dict__`).

Comment: autocompletion is not part of python but IDE.

Comment: FWIW, the usual Python philosophy is for code to be [generous in what it accepts and strict in what it produces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle); imposing unnecessary restrictions on the data that your classes / functions accept makes them less flexible & re-usable, so it should only be done when you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: BTW, `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the built-in `list` type, which can lead to mysterious bugs. Also, `self.y = x * x` is simpler than `self.y = self.x ** 2`.

Comment: Python generally uses "duck typing", it is not considered a typed language but rather a dynamic one. However, your desire to offer some guarantees on parameters and returnvalues is not new and there are approaches to improve python: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+type+hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PEP 484

In Python ≥ 3.0, you can use function annotations ([PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)) with the type hinting semantics of [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Although the latter proposal was only accepted in Python 3.5 and [will be provisional until the release of 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#what-about-existing-uses-of-annotations), it's syntactically backwards compatible to all Python versions supporting PEP 3107, so using type hint annotations in any 3.x version of Python should [*at least* not hurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primum_non_nocere).<sup>[1]</sup>

Whether it *helps* your IDE or interactive interpreter (REPL) to do better autocompletion **is up to that IDE or interpreter**, and maybe its settings, even for Python ≥ 3.5.

For Python 2, an [alternative notation using comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) is available, that tools supporting PEP 0484 might or might not respect.

## Add the type hints you care about

Let's look how the annotation-based hinting (Python 3.x) would look for your code. (Comment based, Python-2.x-compatible hinting is left as an exercise for the reader.)

To indicate that iterating over `MyList` instances yields `MyClass` objects, we hint the return type of `__iter__()` by appending a `->` (Arrow made of a minus and a greater-than sign) after the function definition's colon, followed by the type of the return value. `__iter__()` itself doesn't return a `MyClass`, it returns an iterator. To indicate that it shall be an iterator over `MyClass`, we use the [generic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics) [`Iterator` abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterator) from the [`typing` module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module)<sup>[2]</sup>:

```
from typing import Iterator

class MyClass:
    # ...

class MyList:
    # ...

    def __iter__(self): -> Iterator[MyClass]
        return iter(self.list)
```

To be able to hold this promise, `self.list` must contain only `MyClass` instances. So let's kindly ask our callers to provide such, by type-hinting the `__init__()` argument:

```
from typing import Iterator, Iterable

# ...

class MyList:
    def __init__(self, list: Iterable[MyClass]):
        self.list = list

    def __iter__(self): -> Iterator[MyClass]
        return iter(self.list)
```

Note that I chose the `Iterable` generic abstract base class, not the more specific [`List` generic abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) (nor `Mapping`, `Sequence`, or `AbstractSet`), as your implementation only relies on `iter(...)`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> except maybe readability when overused. So [as Mark writes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-May/140104.html), "please use type-hints responsibly" if you do use them.

<sup>[2]</sup> included in Python ≥ 3.5. For lower versions, use the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.typing) installable with `pip install typing`.

Comment: A very thorough explanation, thanks a lot for that! I will try to include all of this in my code 

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the PyCharm IDE, then you can do this:

```
for i in bar:
    assert isinstance(i, MyClass)
```

or this:

```
for i in bar: # type: MyClass
```

Comment: Yes, I am using PyCharm and even though this is not a solution that will work in all environments, it at least works for me at the moment!  Thanks a lot for this hint! One note here: I not quite the fan of assert statements since it is ignored in some conditions.

Comment: A follow up question: I guess it is not possible to add this to the __iter__ magic method, so the IDE automatically knows that without having to mention that next to the loop all the time...!?

Comment: Just for anyone wondering about the above question: in PyCharm, all this is possible when one writes in the MyList class `self.list = list  # type: list[MyClass]`

Answer (score 1):

Python is not aware of any types until you actually run your code. That is when types are checked and actions based on the type occur.

What you are looking for is an IDE/[REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) feature while developing code. In the default Python REPL this sort of look-up might not be available. In more sophisticated enviroments this does actually happen and you can see the attributes for a given class.

For example, in the [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/) REPL I often use, when inside the loop:

```
for i in bar:
```

I press `i.` and hit `tab` both elements `i.x  i.y` are presented. This is because the `REPL` has been developed to allow for greater introspection while developing code.

I'm pretty sure most well known IDEs provide this; Pythons default REPL is rather simplistic (`3.5`'s has some autocomplete, though! :D) and doesn't offer way too much.

Comment: Actually, even Python 2's REPL can do some autocompletion (at least, on *nix systems), but you have to enable it. The easiest way to do that is with an appropriate PYTHONSTARTUP script, as shown in the [rlcompleter docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rlcompleter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of that. I was not aware that the REPL feature depends on the IDE. 